# How do I move the 2nd picture underneath the other picture with a small gap?

Tags: html, css

I have a few questions:

1. How do I move the 2nd picture underneath the other picture with a small gap?

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

div.container {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 30px;
}

header {
  background-color: #000000;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

header h1 {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  float: left;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.logo {
  margin: 10px 50px;
  height: 120px;
  float: left;
}

.nav {
  float: right;
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px 100px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 5px;
}

ul.nav li a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: inherit;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

.nav li a:hover {
  background: #fff;
  transition: .4s;
  color: #000000
}

.nav li.active a {
  border: 2px solid white;
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #000;
}

.banner-image {
  width: 100%;
}

.body {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.nrl-image {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title> GWS News- Home</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <h1> Grass World Sport News</h1>
      <img src=img/logo.jpg class="logo">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="file:///Users/rarichenjoseph/Desktop/GWS%202/Website.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">World Cup</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sports</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Schedule</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="banner">
      <img class="banner-image" src=img/banner1.jpeg>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="body">
    <h1> Latest Sport News</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="pics">
    <img class="nrl-image" src="img/dvw.jpg">
    <h2> Can St George Illawarra Dragons keep their place on top of the ladder?</h2>
    <p1> Robbie Farah stuns all of Dragons with a match-winning performance that leads to Dragons first loss at their home ground. This win for the Tigers allow them to stay in top 8 and possibly have a chance to win the finals. </p1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img class="world-cup" src="img/wcf.jpg" />
  </div>
</body>
```

When you view the website everything is muddled up at the bottom because the picture come together and kinda messes up the website.

Instead, I want to move the second picture underneath the first one leaving a small gap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `clear: both` and `margin-top` on the image container below to force the other contents below and put a gap inbetween like so

```
<style>

html,body{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

div.container{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 30px;
}

header{
    background-color: #000000;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

header h1{
    color: #ffffff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    float: left;
    font-size: 50px;
 }

.logo{
    margin: 10px 50px;
    height: 120px;
    float: left;
}

.nav {
    float: right;
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 10px 100px;
    margin: 20px;
}

.nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 5px;
}

ul.nav li a{
    color: #ffffff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: inherit;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;

}

.nav li a:hover{
    background: #fff;
    transition: .4s;
    color: #000000
}

.nav li.active a{
    border: 2px solid white;
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #000;
}

.banner-image {
width: 100%;
}

.body{
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.nrl-image{
    float: left;
}

.pic{
  clear: both;
}

</style>

<html>
    <head>
        <title> GWS News- Home</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="container">
                <h1> Grass World Sport News</h1>
                <img src=img/logo.jpg class="logo">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="file:///Users/rarichenjoseph/Desktop/GWS%202/Website.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">World Cup</a>    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sports</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Schedule</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="banner">
                <img class="banner-image" src=img/banner1.jpeg>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div class="body">
            <h1> Latest Sport News</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="pics">
            <div class="nrl-image">
            <img  src="../../../xampp/htdocs/sef/images/avarta2.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div>
            <h2> Can St George Illawarra Dragons keep their place on top of the ladder?</h2>
            <p> Robbie Farah stuns all of Dragons with a match-winning performance that leads to Dragons first loss at their home ground. This win for the Tigers allow them to stay in top 8 and possibly have a chance to win the finals. </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        <div style="margin-top:20px">
            <img class="world-cup" src="../../../xampp/htdocs/sef/images/avarta2.jpg" />
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```